# Mendix: The FileManager widget and uploaded file extensions

Tags: mendix

When using the FileManager widget to upload files, the backing FileDocument entity will contain the binary contents of the uploaded file and metadata about the file. My problem is that I don't know where within the FileDocument entity I can find the uploaded document's file extension. I see that there is a FileDocument attribute called "Name", but this value doesn't contain the file extension. For example, when uploading "myfile.txt" the name attribute will be "myfile". I know the full name is being persisted somewhere so I assume there is an easy way for me to grab it, I just don't know where to look. I need the full file name with the extension because I am storing the newly uploaded document to a remote file-server via a web-service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Name attribute is definitely what you're looking for. It contains the full file name and extension.

Somewhere in your application, the name is getting changed or the extension stripped off.

Comment: @tieniber: thanks for the response. You're right. I just encountered an odd  corner case in my testing where the name was being changed.